# If all the 4 sides of a quadrilateral are equal but only 3 of its angles are equal. Is it a square?

Tags: geometry

If all the 4 sides of a quadrilateral are equal but only 3 of its angles are equal. Is it a square?

I am wondering  if all the four sides are equal and 3 of the 4 interior angles are equal, doesn't it necessarily mean that the 4th angle would also be equal to the rest of the three? Hard time visualizing it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a quadrilateral has its sides equal, it is a rhombus. And if a rhombus has three angles equal, it is a square.

Comment: The opposite angles of a rhombus are equal. So when three are equal to each other then all four are equal to each other.

Comment: That makes sense. Since Opposite angles are equal is so since 3 are equal the fourth one would also be equal.

Comment: @Jason : note that this is true only if the quadrilateral is not crossed (self intersecting), You can have a self intersecting quadrilateral with 4 sides and 4 angles equals, and it's obviously not a square

Comment: Yes, that's true.